# Tried to install a Kernel, now i have mutliple problems!

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates

I tried to upgrade the kernal to 3.8.2 but it didn't work. So after learning that 3.8 wouldn't work with bumblebee I tried to go back and install 3.5.25. It still didn't work.

`uname -r` says: `3.5.0-17-generic`

So here are my problems:

Whenever I try to launch update manager I get this:

```
E: linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic: subprocess installed
post-removal script returned error exit status 1
```

I tried to `sudo rm` the directories but it doesn't help.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to
remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

$ sudo dkpg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (3.5.0-25.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 36: /etc/default/grub: i915.modeset=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic
```

Comment: `I tried to upgrade to 3.8.2` What exactly did you do?

Comment: wow how did you upgrade to `3.8.2`?!!!!

Comment: i followed the tutorial in upbuntu but its good i managed to solve ths problem, i dont even remember how since now i have 2 others problems after updating my graphic cards driver.